# How to create a .wav file using AudioClip.Create in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have these codes to create a audio stream to load in an audio source but I wanna to use .wav file for model collaboration reason, what should I do? ChatGPT has taught me many methods but none works. Plz Help thx

```
     public void TurnTextToSpeech(string _input)
{

    if(audioSource.isPlaying){
        audioSource.Stop();
    }

    lock (threadLocker)
    {
        waitingForSpeak = true;
    }

    string newMessage = null;
    var startTime = DateTime.Now;

    // Starts speech synthesis, and returns once the synthesis is started.
    using (var result = synthesizer.StartSpeakingTextAsync(_input).Result)
    {
        // Native playback is not supported on Unity yet (currently only supported on Windows/Linux Desktop).
        // Use the Unity API to play audio here as a short term solution.
        // Native playback support will be added in the future release.
        var audioDataStream = AudioDataStream.FromResult(result);
        var isFirstAudioChunk = true;
        var audioClip = AudioClip.Create(
            "Speech",
            SampleRate * 600, // Can speak 10mins audio as maximum
            1,
            SampleRate,
            true,
            (float[] audioChunk) =>
            {
                var chunkSize = audioChunk.Length;
                var audioChunkBytes = new byte[chunkSize * 2];
                var readBytes = audioDataStream.ReadData(audioChunkBytes);
                if (isFirstAudioChunk && readBytes > 0)
                {
                    var endTime = DateTime.Now;
                    var latency = endTime.Subtract(startTime).TotalMilliseconds;
                    newMessage = $"Speech synthesis succeeded!\nLatency: {latency} ms.";
                    isFirstAudioChunk = false;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < chunkSize; ++i)
                {
                    if (i < readBytes / 2)
                    {
                        audioChunk[i] = (short)(audioChunkBytes[i * 2 + 1] << 8 | audioChunkBytes[i * 2]) / 32768.0F;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        audioChunk[i] = 0.0f;
                    }
                }

                if (readBytes == 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(200); // Leave some time for the audioSource to finish playback
                    audioSourceNeedStop = true;
                }
            });

        audioSource.clip = audioClip;
        audioSource.Play();
    }

    lock (threadLocker)
    {
        if (newMessage != null)
        {
            message = newMessage;
        }

        waitingForSpeak = false;
    }
}
```

I always get these warning in runtime

Can't get data from streamed samples for audio clip "Speech". If you created the audio clip with AudioClip.Create, set the 'stream' argument to false, so you can access the data with 'AudioClip.GetData'. For a disk-based audio clip, change the load type to 'DecompressOnLoad', so you can access the data with 'AudioClip.GetData'.

I think if I can figure these out , maybe I do not need to create file after all.
but when I change 'stream' argument to false, unity always crush

full error here , now I got that it's lip sync which is using GetData method to cause trouble

```
Can't get data from streamed samples for audio clip "Speech". If you created the audio clip with AudioClip.Create, set the 'stream' argument to false, so you can access the data with 'AudioClip.GetData'. For a disk-based audio clip, change the load type to 'DecompressOnLoad', so you can access the data with 'AudioClip.GetData'.
UnityEngine.AudioClip:GetData (single[],int)
CrazyMinnow.SALSA.Salsa:SalsaLssGetAudioClipData (single[],int)
CrazyMinnow.SALSA.Salsa:AnalyzeAudio ()
CrazyMinnow.SALSA.Salsa:ProcessAudioAnalysis ()
CrazyMinnow.SALSA.Salsa:LateUpdate ()
```